# How to use ElementMeshInterpolation to interpolate to deformed mesh?

Tags: finite-element-method, interpolation, solidmechanics

I'm solving a problem in solid mechanics, but I ran into problems when I tried to plot some stuff over the deformed mesh, because the plots are cut off. They end when the undeformed mesh ends.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

pars = <|"MaterialModel" -> "NeoHookeanIsotropic", "LameParameter" -> 10^6, 
   "ShearModulus" -> 5000, "ModelForm" -> "PlaneStress", "Thickness" -> 0.01, 
   "InitialStress" -> {$MachineEpsilon, $MachineEpsilon}|>;
vars = {{u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y}};
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]];

pde = {SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 
    SolidBoundaryLoadValue[x == 1, vars, 
     pars, <|"Pressure" -> {p, 0}|>], 
   SolidFixedCondition[x == 0, vars, pars]};
AbsoluteTiming[
 displacement = 
   NDSolveValue[
    pde /. p -> 3000, {u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];]

deformedMesh = 
  ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, displacement, "ScalingFactor" -> 1];
```

Now comes the plotting part:

```
F = Map[Grad[#, {x, y}] &, displacement];
h = Function[{x, y}, F . {{1}, {0}} // Flatten // Evaluate];
StreamPlot[h[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] deformedMesh, 
  StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamScale -> None, 
  StreamColorFunction -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

This gives the following result. In the background you can see the deformed mesh, but the lines are cut off at 1. They are plotted only over the undeformed mesh.

[image: fibers]

Same thing happens when I try to plot norm of Cauchy stress.

```
strain = SolidMechanicsStrain[vars, pars, displacement];
cauchyStress = SolidMechanicsStress[vars, pars, strain, displacement];
cauchyNorm = Norm[cauchyStress, "Frobenius"];
ContourPlot[cauchyNorm, {x, y} \[Element] deformedMesh, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The plot is also cut off.

[image: cauchy]

I tried to use `ElementMeshInterpolation` to interpolate to the deformed mesh. I tried to follow the examples in documentation:

```
values = Function[{x, y}, h] @@@ mesh["Coordinates"];
if = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, values];
```

But this results in error "Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for 
machine numbers."

Comment: Have look in the solid mechanics tutorial, there are examples showing how to do this in the introduction art example section. You'd need to map the displacement to the deformed mesh.

Comment: Actually, all functions defined on $\Omega$, not on `deformedMesh`. It is why `StreamPlot` and `ContourPlot` cat off picture.  We can use `VectorDisplacementPlot` to show `h` on  `deformedMesh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
deformedH = 
  Partition[
    ElementMeshInterpolation[deformedMesh, #["ValuesOnGrid"]][x, 
       y] & /@ Flatten[F][[All, 0]], 2] . {1, 0};
StreamPlot[deformedH, {x, y} \[Element] deformedMesh, 
 StreamPoints -> Coarse, StreamScale -> None, 
 StreamColorFunction -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and

```
cauchyNorm2 = EvaluateOnElementMesh[{x, y}, cauchyNorm, mesh];
deformedCauchyNorm = 
  ElementMeshInterpolation[deformedMesh, 
   cauchyNorm2["ValuesOnGrid"]];
ContourPlot[deformedCauchyNorm[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] deformedMesh, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic(*,PlotRange->All*)]
```

[image]

If by, cut off, you mean the re-scaled plot then you can specify `PlotRange->All` to 'fix' that.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck on it for a long time.

Comment: @lemurman Maybe, I should add more such examples in the documentation?

Comment: I think it would be useful.